# When does $[a][b]=[ab]$ hold, where [] is an equivalence class?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the integers. Define $A \boxtimes B $ = $\{ ab  : a \in A,\ b \in B\}$. I want to know what properties an equivalence relation ~ must have such that $[a]\boxtimes[b] = [ab]$. I have already proved that this works for a congruence relation mod m, and trivially, for the relation =. but I am unsure where to begin pinpointing the specific properties that an equivalence relation must have such that this property holds. Proofs of such properties would also be helpful.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are $A,B$ subsets of the integers or some other set with a known product operation?  Or does $ab$ denote a formal string?  And what set is your equivalence relation meant to live on?  $A,B$ or $A\times B$?

Comment: Yes, A,B are subsets of the integers. I'm not so sure what you mean by where my equivalence relation is meant to live on. Not sure if this will be helpful but just to reiterate, A and B are subsets of the integers, where an equivalence relation ~ exists. Then we take 2 arbitrary classes and I want to know if the class of a which is an element in A times the class of b which is an element of B is equal to the class of ab.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate that $A,B$ are subsets of the integers.  That's not stated anywhere in your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any nice characterization. But here's another example: the equivalence relationed defined as $m\sim n$ if the powers of $2$ dividing $m$ and $n$ are the same.

In general, if $f$ is any monoid homomorphism from the domain of your set to another set (so that both sets have multiplications and $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$), then the equivalence relation defined as $m\sim n$ if and only if $f(m)=f(n)$ will have this property. Both your examples have this form: $f(n)=n\mod m$ in the first instance, and $f(n)=n$ in the second instances. The example above also has this form, where the codomain is the multiplicative monoid $\{1,2,4,8,16,\dots\}$.